# How to use chainlink automation to call a function with onlyAdmin modifier?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I have a smart contract that has a function with an onlyAdmin modifier. I want to use chainlink automation to trigger this function based on certain conditions. However, I don’t know which address to define as the admin in my contract.

I have tested it thoroughly by setting another wallet to the onlyAdmin modifier which could call my fnction but when I set the registry address as the admin my transaction goes through but it reverts the execution.

Its a time based logic if thats neccessary and I have even increased the Gas eventho thats not neccessary since calling the function only needs 200k Gas.

[Transaction Receipt of the Perform Upkeep](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x2e9d8882944c4e7ade0cf813249cdc8b5f801ace261592154358a29cbe66ca39)

Comment: Appears to be a Duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341810/how-to-use-chainlink-automation-to-call-a-function-with-onlyadmin-modifier

Answered there.